# .load() strange behaviour, element duplication

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a main navbar, which loads contents - using `.load()` - to a div `data-role=content` according to whats selected,

so i use the `TapHandler` event on the navbar, to load the content like:

```
$("#mainc").load(target, function() {
     $("#index").trigger("pagecreate");  //#index is the page id
});
```

Div where content is being loaded:

```
<div data-role="content" id="mainc">

</div>
```

Whats being loaded: ( the second navbar )

```
<div id="profile_navbar" data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the problem is, the first click, evrything goes perfect, then, it starts duplicating some borders on and on, the more i change tabs, the more borders it gain,

i dont use `.trigger('create')` there, because it doesnt get the loaded content styled with the jqm css.

Images:
[image]

What is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the trigger function is  wrapping new HTML elements around your "buttons". Are you sure that "trigger" is really what you want to call each click?

Comment: well, i've just started with jqm, what else could I do to load .html into content ?, because when i dont trigger that, the content doenst get styled

Comment: Show us your initial page HTML and what are you loading, without it this question is useless. Basically help us help you :)

Comment: edited, nothing much to add, just the .trigger pagecreate is fkin doin that effect, without it evrything goes fine (except that than content wont get styled ), i can link both .html and js if it helps

Comment: use `$('[data-role=content]').trigger('create');` instead of `$('#index').trigger('pagecreate');`

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2bLM6/

Comment: .trigger('create') dont get the content styled for me, I had a question open about that, then some1 answered me : " If you are adding another navbar you must use trigger('pagecreate') because it will enhance whole page. trigger('create') will enhance only content while header and footer will stay intact."

Comment: What jQuery Mobile are you using? I have used jQm 1.3.1 but I can't recreate your problem.

Comment: using 1.3.1, CDN-Hosted

Comment: now you're adding navbar to content div not to header nor footer. so you need to use `$('[data-role=content]').trigger('create');` to enhance content div only and leaving the rest of the page as is. check the demo i added http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2bLM6/

Comment: sry, i had my second navbar inside a <div data-role="header">, css aplyed now with $('[data-role=content]').trigger('create'); but still strange behaviour: http://i.imgur.com/ddYhHG2.png

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle of your example?

Comment: are you removing the old navbar before appnding a new one? use `$('[data-role=navbar]').remove()` and then append a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of struggle, I found that the problem was not with `.trigger(“pagecreate”)` but with `.load()`

So i came up with this: (dont ask me why, all I know is that it works this way)

```
$.get(target, function(data) {
    $('#mainc').html(data);
    $('#mainc').trigger("create");
});
```

instead of:

```
$("#mainc").load(target, function() {
    $('#mainc').trigger("create");
});
```